# Quando usar recursão e quando usar laços?

Tags: funções, loop, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, recursão

Um problema pode ser resolvido e obter o mesmo resultado utilizado um *loop* ou através de [chamadas recursivas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) a uma função.

Considerando que a linguagem de programação sendo usada possua os dois recursos, como saber quando um é melhor que o outro?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A resposta depende muito do contexto.

## Situações em que usar recursão

### Quando o desempenho for igual ou superior à versão iterativa do código

Há várias situações onde usar recursão é mais eficiente.

Uma delas é quando se sabe de antemão que não haverão muitos níveis de chamada e a versão iterativa gastaria mais processamento e memória com uma pilha de estados.

Outra é quando há a possibilidade de Otimização de Chamada em Cauda (*Tail Call Optimization*), como já [discutido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2467/227) aqui no SOPT em [algumas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4282/227) [perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3959/como-simular-recurs%C3%A3o-de-cauda-no-c).

### Quando a versão iterativa é complicada demais

Toda implementação recursiva pode ser "convertida" em iterativa de alguma forma. Em último caso, usa-se uma pilha para simular o estado de cada chamada. Veja [alguns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094679/is-there-a-problem-that-has-only-a-recursive-solution?lq=1) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931762/1683070) [do SO em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011448/1683070) para uma discussão mais completa.

O problema é que às vezes a solução é tão mais complexa que na prática a versão recursiva tem um melhor custo-benefício. Um exemplo que conheço pessoalmente é o caso que pode ser vista na minha pergunta e resposta sobre [a versão iterativa (não recursiva) do algoritmo LCA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1242/227).

### Quanto técnicas naturalmente usadas em recursão puderem ser utilizadas

Algoritmos recursivos naturalmente podem obter vantagens de técnicas de *caching* e *[memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)* para obter resultados muito mais rápidos.

## Situações em que não devemos usar recursão

A recursão como regra geral deve ser evitada principalmente pelos seguintes motivos:

- Comumente produz código complexo, de mais difícil manutenção e entendimento
- Pode dar origem a mais um site de perguntas e respostas, i.e., causar um StackOverflow, após estourar o empilhamento máximo da linguagem ou do processador.

## Conclusão

Não há uma resposta absoluta, pois há casos onde a solução iterativa é difícil de se obter ou tem desempenho inferior à recursiva. Porém, sempre que possível deve-se optar por uma solução não recursiva.

Comment: Não se esqueçam de ver este [complemento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21881/101)

Comment: Acho que há uma forma mais simples de responder: use recursão quando o problema sendo resolvido for recursivo (cálculos de fórmulas recursivas, mergesort, quicksort, destruição de estruturas de árvore, etc) e se, além disso, sua solução usando laços for complexa demais (caso contrário, evite recursão devido ao fato da recursão ter alto custo de memória e processamento). Há casos em que a recursão pode ser implementada sem precisar re-chamar a função mas sim empilhando dados, como é o caso da remoção de árvores.

Answer (score 14):

Concordo com [a resposta do utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21567/215), gostaria somente de dar o seguinte complemento:

> Considerando que uma linguagem de programação sendo usada possua os dois recursos...

*Possuir* os dois recursos não basta, também é importante saber se eles são implementados com eficiência e se são usados extensivamente em programas escritos naquela linguagem.

Quanto à eficiência, metade da resposta já foi dada: a linguagem precisa dar suporte a Otimização de Chamada em Cauda (Tail Call Optimization) para a recursão ser viável na maioria dos casos. A menos que para um problema em particular a solução iterativa *também* empregue uma pilha, e essa pilha seja tão ou mais ineficiente em consumo de memória que a pilha de chamada, as funções recursivas [ingênuas] serão em geral menos eficientes que as iterativas.

A outra metade refere-se a linguagens que dão suporte a construções iterativas, mas que o *modus operandi* das mesmas seja recursivo por natureza. Nesse caso, há a possibilidade da versão iterativa do programa ser **menos eficiente** que a versão recursiva! Exemplo (Prolog; comentários em JavaScript):

```prolog
soma(Inicio, Fim, Return) :-    %  function soma(Inicio, Fim) {
    dynamic(x/1),               %      var x;
    assertz(x(0)),              %      x = 0;
    between(Inicio, Fim, N),    %      for ( var N = Inicio ; N <= Fim ; N++ ) {
        retract(x(X)),          %          var X = x; x = undefined;
        X1 is X + N,            %          var X1 = X + N;
        assertz(x(X1)),         %          var x = X1;
        fail;                   %      }
    x(Return),                  %      return x;
    abolish(x/1).               %  }   // acabou o escopo de x

?- soma(1, 10, Resultado).
Resultado = 55.
```

Tirando o fato da sintaxe ser feia e verbosa (o que poderia ser facilmente corrigido com um [açúcar sintático](http://www.deransart.fr/prolog/bips.html#operators)), o problema desse código é que o uso de `assert` e `retract` é relativamente caro em Prolog, de modo que uma solução recursiva [com recursão de cauda] seria bem mais eficiente:

```prolog
soma(Inicio, Fim, Return) :- soma(Inicio, Fim, Fim, Return). /* Resultado Parcial = Fim */

soma(Inicio, Inicio, RParcial, RParcial).  /* Se o início for igual ao fim, retorne o Res. Parcial */
soma(Inicio, Fim, RParcial, Return) :-
    RParcial1 is RParcial + Inicio,        
    Proximo is Inicio + 1,
    soma(Proximo, Fim, RParcial1, Return).
```

Quanto a ser usado extensivamente, aí entra a questão da uniformidade do código e manutenabilidade. Se a grande maioria dos programas na linguagem X usa iteração, usar recursão quando existe uma alternativa perfeitamente simples, concisa e eficiente que resolva o mesmo problema via iteração, é querer procurar problema:

1. Quem for pegar o código pra dar manutenção vai ter mais dificuldade de entendê-lo, de modo que você gastará mais tempo "treinando seu substituto";

   - Independentemente de ser um caso de "menor denominador comum" ou não: eu próprio tenho *muita* experiência com recursão (trabalhei um tempo com Prolog no passado), mas se eu herdasse um código Java ou Python e ele estivesse nesse formato, provavelmente eu o reescreveria na primeira ocasião em que ele apresentasse problemas.
2. As ferramentas e técnicas de depuração da linguagem provavelmente serão melhores adaptadas para lidar com código iterativo do que com recursivo;
3. Os relatórios de erros (*stack trace* por exemplo) tendem a ficar bem grandes, pois também são mais adaptados para lidar com código iterativo;
4. Idem para ferramentas de *profiling* (*Nota:* especulação - não tenho dados concretos/experiência sobre o assunto para servir de base para essa afirmação);
5. Por essas razões, esse código será um forte candidato a ser reescrito no futuro, acarretando em retrabalho.

Os mesmos argumentos *devem* valer também para o cenário oposto (usar iteração numa linguagem predominantemente recursiva), mas não tenho experiência suficiente para opinar (no caso de Prolog, há muitas situações em que a iteração é a melhor ferramenta sim, ao contrário da impressão que um iniciante nessa linguagem possa ter - há até [um *built-in* específico para isso...](http://www.deransart.fr/prolog/bips.html#repeat)).

Answer (score 6):

**Sempre que possível evite este recurso**. Chamadas recursivas são interessantes e elegantes mais elas ***gastam mais memoria*** (porque tem que armazenar as N chamadas recursivas e retornando-as respectivamente) e em plataformas mais limitadas como PIC, você pode estourar o limite do PC se não tomar cuidado (120 chamadas) na família PIC18.

Por outro lado existem problemas nos quais o uso de recursão é comum pois para resolver o problema sem recursão precisaria-se de criar uma pilha para manter a ordem das chamadas como na `torre de hanoi` ou no `mergesort`.

Editado:

A resposta estava errada pois todo problema recursivo pode ser escrito na forma de loop [(referência)](http://www.alanturing.net/turing_archive/pages/Reference%20Articles/The%20Turing-Church%20Thesis.html).

Dica de leitura: [Como remover recursão usando pilha - (inglês)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and)

Comment: `Por outro lado existem problemas que só podem ser resolvidos por recursão` Citation needed.

Comment: @Renan, corrigi a resposta estava errada.

Comment: @Renan fiquei curioso, poderia dar um exemplo que só é possível resolver com chamadas recursivas?

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett, Todo problema recursivo pode ser escrito como iterativo (veja a referência para mais detalhes).

Comment: Eu tenho um exemplo de um problema que só pode ser resolvido com chamada recursiva: como estourar a pilha de execução com uma única rotina? :D Brincadeiras a parte, +1.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun sempre levei em consideração isso... só fiquei na dúvida mesmo se havia alguma exceção