# Métodos Recursivos VS Iteração

Tags: java

Qual é a diferença entre métodos recursivos e iteração e quais são as vantagens de se usar as duas abordagens em um programa java?

Comment: Acho que já foi respondido aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Iteratividade** é melhor que recursividade, quando estamos analisando desempenho. A legibilidade de códigos iterativos requer alguma experiência do programador, principalmente em códigos maiores, com muitos laços aninhados.

**Recursividade** confere ao código maior legibilidade, tornando mais simples sua compreensão. Para pequenas aplicações, muitas vezes a recursividade apresenta perda tolerável de desempenho. Existem ainda técnicas, como memoizing (caching), que podem equiparar a compexidade algoritmica ao programa iterativo.

> https://dietkx.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/recursividade-x-iteratividade/

**Exemplo utilizando Iteração**

```c
int FibonacciIterativo(int termo) {
    int termo1 = 1, fibo = 0, temp = 0;
    for (int cont = 1;cont <= termo-1; cont++) {
        temp = fibo; //faz o giro, a variável temp serve somente para que não sejam perdidos valores
        fibo += termo1; //observe, são necessárias 3 variáveis
        termo1 = temp;
    }
    return fibo;
}
```

**Exemplo utilizando Recursividade**

```c
int FibonacciRecursivo(int termo){
   int primeiro = 0, segundo = 1, retorno = -2;
   if(termo == 1)
       retorno = primeiro;
   else if (termo == 2)
       retorno = segundo;
   else
       retorno = FibonacciRecursivo(termo-1) + FibonacciRecursivo(termo-2);
   return retorno;
}
```

**Recursivo em 1 linha com operador ternário**

```
int FibonacciRecursivoComOperadorTernario(int termo) {
    return (termo == 1 || termo == 2) ? 1 : FibonacciRecursivoComOperadorTernario(termo - 1) + FibonacciRecursivoComOperadorTernario(termo - 2);
}
```

Métodos recursivos gastam mais recurso de processamento.
Normalmente utiliza métodos recursivos para soluções em que iterações não são viáveis.

[Aqui](http://www.50minutos.com.br/post/Desempenho-de-novo-recursividade-x-iteratividade-com-Fibonacci.aspx) tem uma comparação entre os dois tipos de métodos.

Comment: Obrigado. Foi muito claro sua explicação.

Comment: O `FibonacciRecursivo` e o `FibonacciRecursivoComOperadorTernario` executam em tempo exponencial, sendo muito pior do que a alternativa iterativa. É possível reescrevê-los de uma forma a manter o tempo de execução linear sem sacrificar a recursividade e nem a legibilidade. Se você deixar assim, vai ter gente copiando este código sem saber o grande problema que ele tem.

Comment: Qual seria essa forma?

Comment: Usar o memoizing, ou então fazer uma sobrecarga com o `FibonacciRecursivo` aonde o retorno é um array de tamanho 2, aonde um dos elementos é reutilizado.

Comment: Então, eu mencionei esses metodos na resposta, só não expliquei... vou dar uma incrementada