# Problema com a estrutura do codigo dentro do switch case

Tags: java, matriz, switch

Ao escolher a opção 1 (fácil) o programa entra no case 1 corretamente, mas quando escolho a porta (0, 1 ou 2) ele volta para o menu, o objetivo é que caso a porta seja a certa ele passe para a linha seguinte com a nova sequencia de portas (segunda linha da matriz) e caso não seja a porta correta o usuário deverá tentar novamente. Obrigado.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;
public class Ejerc9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int opcion = 0;
            int tenta =0;
            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            int [][] porta = new int [3][3];
            Random r = new Random();
            // para cada linha
            int qual=0;
            int cont1=0;
            int cont2=0;
            int count3=0;

            while (opcion != 4) {
                System.out.println ("Juego de las 3 Puertas, intente acertar la puerta buena");
                System.out.println ("Elige la dificuldad:");
                System.out.println ();
                System.out.println ("1.Facil");
                System.out.println ("2. Medio");
                System.out.println ("3. Avanzado");
                System.out.println ("4. Salir");
                System.out.println ();

                String opcionStr = in.readLine ();
                opcion = Integer.parseInt(opcionStr);

                while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 4) {
                    System.out.println ("Elige la dificuldad (1,2,3):");
                    System.out.println ();
                    System.out.println ("1.Facil");
                    System.out.println ("2. Medio");
                    System.out.println ("3. Avanzado");
                    System.out.println ("4. Salir");
                    System.out.println ();

                    opcionStr = in.readLine ();
                    opcion = Integer.parseInt(opcionStr);
                }

                switch (opcion) {
                  case 1:
                    qual = r.nextInt(3);
                    for(i =0; i<3;i++){
                        qual = r.nextInt(3);
                        porta[i][qual] = 1;
                        for(j=0; j<3;j++){
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
                    String tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                    tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
                    while(tenta<0|tenta>2){
                        System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta valida: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
                        tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                        tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);

                        while(tenta!=porta[0][qual]){

                            System.out.println ("Elige otra Puerta");

                            tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                            tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
                        }
                        if(tenta==porta[0][qual]){
                            i++;
                            cont1=cont1+1;
                            System.out.println (" Nivel 2 -Elige una Puerta : Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
                            tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                            int tenta2 = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
                            while(tenta2<0|tenta2>2){
                                System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta valida: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
                                tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                            tenta2 = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);}
                            while(tenta2!=porta[1][qual]){

                                System.out.println ("Elige otra Puerta");

                                tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                                tenta2 = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
                            }

                            if(tenta2==porta[1][qual]){
                                i++;
                                cont1=cont1+1;

                                System.out.println (" Nivel 3 -Elige una Puerta : Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
                                tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                                int tenta3 = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
                                while(tenta3<0|tenta3>2){
                                    System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta valida: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
                                    tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                                tenta3 = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);}
                                while(tenta3!=porta[2][qual]){

                                    System.out.println ("Elige otra Puerta");

                                    tentaStr = in.readLine ();
                                    tenta3 = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
                                }
                                if(tenta3==porta[2][qual]){
                                    i++;
                                cont1=cont1+1;}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(cont1==3){
                        System.out.println ("Congrats!!!");
                    }
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    break;
                  case 4:
                    System.out.println("Hasta luego.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error 400" +e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu @mgibsonbr, você poderia me indicar o caminho da luz para deixa-lo menos "macarrônico"? hehehe. Só uma dica mesmo. Obrigado.

Comment: Troquei para for, ficou assim: ainda tenho que lapidar mas tá quase lá.

Comment: for(i =0; i<porta.length;i++){
         
             System.out.println("Nivel "+i);
      for(j=0;      j<porta.length;j++){
       System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta: Tenemos las puertas 0,1,2");
       String tentaStr = in.readLine ();
       tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
     }
     if(porta[i][tenta] !=1){continue;}
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo o seu código está contido dentro de um loop que testa por uma entrada **inválida**:

```
// Pede uma porta
System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
String tentaStr = in.readLine ();
tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);

// Se a porta for INVÁLIDA, repete esse loop
while(tenta<0|tenta>2){
    // Pede outra porta
    System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta valida: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
    tentaStr = in.readLine ();
    tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);

    // NÃO testa se a nova entrada foi válida!!!
    while(tenta!=porta[0][qual]){ // Entre no jogo
        ...
```

Ou seja, a menos que o usuário entre com uma entrada inválida na sua primeira tentativa, ele não vai sequer entrar no jogo...

Para resolver, você precisa encerrar esse loop que repete a entrada no caso inválido, e só entrar no jogo em si quando a entrada for **válida**:

```
// Pede uma porta
System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
String tentaStr = in.readLine ();
tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);

// Se a porta for INVÁLIDA, repete esse loop
while(tenta<0|tenta>2){
    // Pede outra porta
    System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta valida: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
    tentaStr = in.readLine ();
    tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
}

// Agora temos certeza que a entrada é válida (pois saiu do loop de cima)
while(tenta!=porta[0][qual]){ // Entre no jogo
    ...
```

P.S. Da forma como está, é muito difícil entender o que o código está fazendo, pois há loop dentro de loop dentro de loop, e tudo numa função só... Sugiro quebrá-lo em funções menores, para melhor entendimento e manutenabilidade (eu por exemplo só consegui enxergar o problema de fato depois que comecei esse processo):

```
public class Ejerc9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int opcion = 0;
            Random r = new Random();

            while (opcion != 4) {
                System.out.println ("Juego de las 3 Puertas, intente acertar la puerta buena");
                opcion = dificuldad("");

                while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 4) {
                    opcion = dificuldad(" (1,2,3)");
                }

                switch (opcion) {
                  case 1:
                    dif1(in, r);
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    break;
                  case 3:
                    break;
                  case 4:
                    System.out.println("Hasta luego.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error 400" +e);
        }
    }

    private static int dificuldad(String etc) {
        System.out.println ("Elige la dificuldad" + etc + ":");
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("1.Facil");
        System.out.println ("2. Medio");
        System.out.println ("3. Avanzado");
        System.out.println ("4. Salir");
        System.out.println ();

        String opcionStr = in.readLine ();
        return Integer.parseInt(opcionStr);
    }

    private static void dif1(BufferedReader in, Random r) {
        int tenta =0;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int [][] porta = new int [3][3];
        // para cada linha
        int cont1=0;
        int cont2=0;
        int count3=0;

        criaPorta(porta, r);

        System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
        tenta = escolhePorta(in);

        while(tenta!=porta[0][qual]){
            System.out.println ("Elige otra Puerta");
            tenta = escolhePorta(in);
        }

        if(tenta==porta[0][qual]){
            i++;
            cont1=cont1+1;
            System.out.println (" Nivel 2 -Elige una Puerta : Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
            int tenta2 = escolhePorta(in);
            while(tenta2!=porta[1][qual]){

                System.out.println ("Elige otra Puerta");
                tenta2 = escolhePorta(in);
            }

            if(tenta2==porta[1][qual]){
                i++;
                cont1=cont1+1;

                System.out.println (" Nivel 3 -Elige una Puerta : Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
                int tenta3 = escolhePorta(in);
                while(tenta3!=porta[2][qual]){

                    System.out.println ("Elige otra Puerta");
                    tenta3 = escolhePorta(in);
                }
                if(tenta3==porta[2][qual]){
                    i++;
                    cont1=cont1+1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(cont1==3){
            System.out.println ("Congrats!!!");
        }
    }

    private static void criaPorta(int[][] porta, Random r) {
        int qual = r.nextInt(3);
        for(i =0; i<3;i++){
            qual = r.nextInt(3);
            porta[i][qual] = 1;
            for(j=0; j<3;j++){
            }
        }
    }

    private static int escolherPorta(BufferedReader in) {
        String tentaStr = in.readLine ();
        int tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
        while(tenta<0|tenta>2){
            System.out.println ("Elige una Puerta valida: Tenemos las puertas 0, 1 y 2");
            tentaStr = in.readLine ();
            tenta = Integer.parseInt(tentaStr);
        }
        return tenta;
    }
}
```

Eu parei logo que identifiquei o problema, mas sugiro que continue (i.e. identificando trechos comuns e colocando em funções). Vejo por exemplo que cada nível está contido dentro do nível anterior (i.e. loop dentro de loop). Desafio: como você faria se em vez de 3 fossem 50 níveis? Ou se o número de níveis fosse informado pelo usuário? Há ao menos duas maneiras de fazer isso, de forma [iterativa ou recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/215)... :P

P.P.S. `tenta<0|tenta>2` é um OU binário (*bitwise*), que até funciona no caso do tipo `boolean` do Java, mas não seria melhor usar um OU booleano? `tenta<0 || tenta>2`

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Estou aprendendo agora essa parte das funções mas vou tentar fazer como você falou.