# Refazer a instrução do método

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para refazer a instrução de um método ate que o usuário cancele.

Tenho o seguinte método, por exemplo:

```
public static void method(){
  int i = 1;
  i += 1;
  String choise;

  println("Exit?");
  choise = scan.next();

  if(choise.equals("y")){
    System.Exit(0);
  } else if(choise.equals("n")){
    /* ???? */
  } else{
    ...
  }
}
```

Imagino que eu poderia usar um loop, do while por exemplo, e executar a instrução ate que choise seja "n". Porem eu gostaria de saber se era possível fazer isso de outro forma sem ser usando um loop.

Comment: Tem muitas alternativas. O que é a ação para se ter é contra ação?

Comment: Então. A ideia e que sempre que o usuário digitar "N" ele refaça o i += 1; assumindo que o estado da variável é 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podemos resolver um mesmo problema de forma `iterativa` (utilizado um laço de repetição) ou através de `chamadas recursivas a uma função`.

A `recursividade` é a definição de uma `sub-rotina` (`função` ou `método`) que pode invocar a si mesma.

Sabendo que temos mais de uma possibilidade de solução devemos sempre buscar a melhor para cada situação [quando usar recursão ou laços](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21551/quando-usar-recurs%C3%A3o-e-quando-usar-la%C3%A7os/21567#21567), no seu caso a solução ideal é através de um `laço de repetição`:

```
while (choise.equals("y")){

    println("Exit?");
    choise = scan.next();

    if(choise.equals("y")){
        System.Exit(0);
    } else if(choise.equals("n")){
        /* ... */
    } else {
        /* ... */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Tente isso:

```
while (choise.equals("y")){
    println("Exit?");
    choise = scan.next();

    if(choise.equals("y")){
        System.Exit(0);
    } else if(choise.equals("n")){
        /* ???? */
    } else{
        ...
    }
}
```

Ou você pode usar um outro método recursivo, que chame a si mesmo caso não seja Y.

Comment: Recursividade para um *loop* normal não me parece boa ideia. Ainda pode incorrer numa clássica `StackOverflow` Exception!

Comment: Foi como eu disse KalebeMtos; Eu poderia usar um loop, mas a titulo de estudos e conhecimento, gostaria de saber outra forma possível.

Comment: Esta é a solução correta. Só tiraria a indicação do recursivo que quase nunca é a solução, neste caso não é mesmo.

Answer (score -2):

Não usa só referencia

```
else if(choise.equals("n")){
      method();
    } else{
```

Comment: Perfeito. Imaginei algo parecido com isso, mas não consegui testar.

Comment: Esta solução não deve ser usada, isto causará problema na pilha de chamadas.

Comment: Recursividade para o problema em questão ? Não é de todo boa ideia, como comentei na outra resposta

Comment: @Joseliz cara podemos sempre responder o que nós é pedido somente, mas o ideial é buscarmos a excelência em nossas respostas,  devemos entender o porque da pergunta e orientar o que é melhor

Comment: "se era possível fazer isso de outro forma sem ser usando um loop". É de todo possível mas você não só não explicou o seu código, como não deu qualquer indicação se seria bom ou mau fazer dessa forma, assim como não mostrou como seria feito com `while` que o código da pergunta não tem. Convém termos em mente que as respostas no *SOPT* servem de referência para futuros leitores por isso devemos tentar o máximo possível incutir boas práticas e dar soluções verdadeiramente boas.

Comment: Como eu disse. Eu sei usar loops. E independente do que  função esta fazendo, ate pq no caso foi um exemplo rápido que fiz, eu queria saber outra forma de fazer o repeat sem usar um loop. Agora que vi que pode se usar funções recursivas, irei estudar o que é e quando usar. Isso ja me basta!