# Como incrementar uma variável em Python?

Tags: python, algoritmo

Eu estou tentando fazer um programa onde ele joga uma letra na tela você aperta ela e supostamente você deveria ganhar um ponto por isso, eu sei que essa é provavelmente uma questão muito idiota, mas eu tentei de varias maneiras e não consegui.

```
import random


def main():
    x = random.randint(0,25)
    ponto = 0

    letra = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    rletra = letra[x]

    print (rletra)


    print ('Sua pontuação é:', ponto)

    a = input('')

    if a == rletra:

        ponto += 1
        print ('Sua pontuação é:', ponto)

        main()

    else:
        print('errado')
main()
```

A única coisa que acontece é que o valor de ponto vai pra 1 e não aumenta.

Comment: Tem como ajustar a indentação do teu código? Senão não dá pra saber se o código está errado ou é falha na indentação.

Comment: Ao invés de recursividade, que não faz muito sentido nesse caso, por que não uma um laço de repetição?

Comment: É que eu não sei muito bem formatar código por aqui, mas acho que agora ta certo

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss e como eu faria isso? usando um for?

Comment: E quando deve encerrar? Sem um critério nunca terminaria, é isto que deseja?

Comment: @Maniero só encerra quando o usuário errar a letra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pergunta não é boba, e está fazendo como deve, aprender com coisas básicas. Talvez o erro só tenha sido tentar algo sem conhecer, começou usar [recursividade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101) por acidente. Isso significa que precisa voltar um pouquinho antes para conhecer algumas coisas mais básicas, e aprender fazer um dos laços mais simples que existe que é o laço sem condição para terminar explicitado nele.

Claro, tem que terminar em algum momento e em comentário foi descrito quando deve terminar, e aí a própria condição existente pode ser usada para terminar, porque o falso do `if` existente atende ao término muito bem. Só precisa aprender o `break` que encerra um laço naquele momento e só costuma fazer sentido dentro de um `if` mesmo, ou seja, ser condicional.

Do jeito que estava fazendo criar um novo escopo em cada execução, e tudo ocorria do zero, portanto a pontuação zerava todas as vezes. Assim fica mais controlado porque algumas instruções só são executadas uma vez, e não cria novo escopo, por isso a variável mantém seu valor.

Melhorei algumas outras coisas, espero que sirva de aprendizado.

```
import random

def main():
    pontos = 0
    letra = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    while True:    
        rletra = letra[random.randint(0, 25)]
        print(rletra)
        if input('') == rletra:
            pontos += 1
            print('Sua pontuação é:', pontos)
        else:
            print('errado')
            break
main()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/z9XrNT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/syzpewfa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/LoopEscope.py).

Comment: Obrigado, consegui entender a parte sobre criar um escopo novo toda a vez que fechava o if

Comment: tem como fazer recursivo, mas não é adequado pra isso e complicado demais. Agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.