# Como posso criar uma função em JavaScript para o prompt?

Tags: javascript, numeração

Como posso criar uma função para deixar que o prompt seja fornecido com os códigos 1 e 2 em javascript?

Caso ele não seja para algum desses dois continue no mesmo prompt. E se para continua o código ...

Se der tem como deixar o prompt de uma função? para que uma função seja usada em vários solicita diferente ...

Muito obrigado

Comment: *" para deixar que o pronto seja fornecido"* não entendi o que isso quer dizer

Comment: Importante [edit] o post explicando melhor o que tentou e o que não deu certo, preferencialmente com um [mcve] do problema, para que seja viável uma resposta. Para entender melhor o site, faça o [Tour] e dê uma lidinha em [Ask] e [Help].

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta não tem como ser mais clara, até porque é uma coisa simples de se fazer. Eu vejo que na maioria dos casos aqui na comunidade as pessoas talvez não saibam 100% a nomenclatura do que elas querem, por exemplo o rapaz, se ele está começando na área e precisa de ajuda com algo simples assim, talvez nem saiba mesmo o que é um loop while. Acredito que isso faça com que muitas pessoas que entram aqui talvez não voltem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use um `while` para fazer a função continuar enquanto não for digitado um valor válido:

```js
function validar() {
  var opcao = "0"
  
  while (opcao != "1" && opcao != "2") {
    opcao = prompt("Digite uma opção (1 ou 2)");
  }
  
  return opcao;
}


alert("Opção escolhida: " + validar());
```

Comment: não consegui entender os downvotes, o que tem de tão ruim na resposta?

Comment: amigo, muito obrigado pela resposta, por acaso teria como a função interagir com um prompt que esta fora dela?

Comment: sim, poderia passar o valor para ela: `function validar(opcao)` mas me parece estranho, sugiro criar outra pergunta explicando isso dai podemos ajudar ;)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401280/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-uma-function-verificar-um-prompt-que-esta-fora-dela

Comment: Criei outra pergunta, teria como dar um exemplo la?

Answer (score -3):

Olá.

A função `num()` vai continua quando for diferente de `1 ou 2`.

Quando for `1 ou 2`,aparecerá uma mensagem na tela.

## Solução

```js
function num() {
  var call = prompt();
  var ret = ["1","2","stop"];
  while (!ret.includes(call)) {
    call = prompt();
  }
  if (call == "stop") { return; } else {
  alert("Valor permitido")}
}
num();
```

Comment: Só uma dica: usar recursão (ou seja, chamar a função `num` dentro dela mesma) pode causar um [estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976375), ainda mais em um caso desse, em que vc não controla a condição de saída (pois ela depende do que for digitado). Sem contar que, caso o usuário digite vários valores inválidos, quando for digitado 1 ou 2, a mensagem do alert será impressa várias vezes. O melhor seria usar um loop mesmo, como sugeriu a resposta do Ricardo (que não tem estouro de pilha, não importa quantos números inválidos sejam digitados, e mostra a mensagem só uma vez) :-)

Comment: Para saber mais sobre "recursão vs loops": https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052 e https://stackoverflow.com/q/660337

Comment: @hkotsubo código funcionou,ele queria que repetisse se fosse diferente.

Comment: Outra dica: como um usuário experiente do site costuma dizer, ["funcionar é diferente de estar certo"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyzrV.jpg). Recursão, apesar de "funcionar", não é a solução mais adequada para este caso, pelos motivos já mencionados. Aliás, que bom que vc editou a resposta e retirou a recursão. Para entender melhor a diferença, teste os 2 códigos (o anterior e o atual), digitando várias vezes o 5 e depois o 2, e veja a diferença (a recursão chama o alert várias vezes no final, o loop chama apenas uma).

Comment: Desculpe eu esqueci. Eu fui testar deu loop infinito. 