# Método recursivo em Python que devolva quantas vezes um determinado elemento aparece num vetor

Tags: python, recursão

Quero fazer um método recursivo em Python que devolva quantas vezes um elemento aparece em um vetor. Abaixo segue meu código usando a busca binária:

```
    def binaryrec(valor, itens, menor, maior):
    vezes = 0
    maior = len(itens) if maior is None else maior
    pos = menor + (maior - menor) // (len(itens) // 2)

    if pos == len(itens):
        return False
    for i in range(len(itens)):
        if itens[pos] == valor:
            vezes = vezes + 1
            return vezes
    if maior == menor:
        return -1
    elif itens[pos] < valor:
        return binaryrec(valor, itens, pos + 1, maior)
    else:
        assert itens[pos] > valor
        return binaryrec(valor, itens, menor, pos)

itens = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 30, 70, 80]
valor = 30
maior = 80
menor = 0
r = binaryrec(valor, itens, menor, maior)
print(r)
```

Comment: Primeira observacao, voce tem que ordenar o seu array de itens para conseguir fazer uma busca binaria efetiva. seu array: itens = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 30, 70, 80] tem 30 depois do 40. Se seu array itens nao estiver em ordenado eh mais rapido voce ir elemento por elemento para contar as ocorrencies. Se seu array itens ja estiver ordenado busca binaria eh uma solucao mais rapida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, [recursão **não** é a melhor forma de resolver esse problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052) (veremos opções não-recursivas no final). E busca binária só faz sentido em listas ordenadas (mesmo assim, a busca binária serve para encontrar um único elemento, não para contar quantas vezes um elemento ocorre).

Enfim, uma forma de resolver é:

```
def count(lista, valor):
    if not lista: # lista vazia
        return 0
    c = 1 if lista[0] == valor else 0
    return c + count(lista[1:], valor)

itens = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 30, 70, 80]
print(count(itens, 30)) # 3
```

Ou seja, se a lista for vazia, retorna zero. Senão, verifica se o primeiro elemento é igual ao valor (e aí eu decido se contabilizo 1 ou 0).

Depois eu somo isso (o 1 ou 0) com a contagem do restante da lista: `lista[1:]` cria uma sub-lista contendo do segundo elemento em diante.

Não é lá muito eficiente porque cria várias sub-listas, além de poder [estourar a pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001) se a lista for muito grande, [veja](https://ideone.com/qAm7D1).

---

Outra alternativa é passar o índice a ser verificado:

```
def count(lista, valor, i=0):
    if i >= len(lista):
        return 0
    c = 1 if lista[i] == valor else 0
    return c + count(lista, valor, i + 1)

itens = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 30, 70, 80]
print(count(itens, 30)) # 3
```

Essa é menos pior que a anterior porque não cria sub-listas, mas também tem o problema do estouro de pilha, [veja](https://ideone.com/ojk4mJ).

---

## Até dá para usar busca binária

Você pode usar busca binária para encontrar a posição do elemento. Mas como já dito, busca binária só funciona se a lista estiver ordenada, então primeiro você deve ordená-la.

Em seguida, como a lista está ordenada, basta verificar os elementos da direita e da esquerda do elemento encontrado e obter a contagem total:

```
# retorna a posição do valor na lista (ou -1 se não for encontrado)
def busca_binaria(lista, inicio, fim, valor):
    if (fim < inicio):
        return -1

    meio = inicio + (fim - inicio) // 2
    if lista[meio] == valor:
        return meio

    if lista[meio] > valor:
        return busca_binaria(lista, inicio, meio - 1, valor)

    return busca_binaria(lista, meio + 1, fim, valor)

def count(lista, valor):
    # busca o índice do elemento
    ind = busca_binaria(lista, 0, len(lista) - 1, valor)
    # elemento não existe na lista
    if ind == -1:
        return 0

    count = 1
    # verifica os elementos à esquerda
    left = ind - 1
    while left >= 0 and lista[left] == valor:
        count += 1
        left -= 1

    # verifica os elementos à direita
    right = ind + 1
    while right < len(lista) and lista[right] == valor:
        count += 1
        right += 1

    return count 

itens = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 30, 70, 80]
itens.sort()
print(count(itens, 30)) # 3
```

---

## Não use recursão para este caso

Como já dito, as melhores soluções são as não-recursivas. A mais simples é usar o que já tem pronto na linguagem:

```
print(itens.count(30))
```

Mas se quiser fazer manualmente:

```
cont = 0
for valor in itens:
    if valor == 30:
        cont += 1
print(cont)
```

Ou ainda:

```
print(len(list(filter(lambda x: x == 30, itens))))

# ou
print(sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda x: x == 30, itens)))
```