# problemas com a função return

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

Estou tentando fazer um programa em que a pessoa tem  que escrever um número, porém quando ela escreve um número que não se encaixa nos requisitos ela tem que escrever outro.

Não consigo usar a função `return` corretamente:

```
def pergunta():
    t = int(input('digite um numero: '))
    dois = t<3
    if dois:
        print ('tente outro')
        return t
    else:
        print ('esse numero ai, parabéns')

pergunta()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`return` encerra a execução da função](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement). Ou seja, se o código chegar ali no `return`, ele sai da função e não executa mais nada do que está dentro da função.

Se quer repetir algo, use um loop simples:

```
def pergunta():
    while True:
        t = int(input('digite um numero: '))
        if t < 3:
            print ('tente outro')
        else:
            print ('esse numero ai, parabéns')
            return t
 
pergunta()
```

Assim, se o número digitado for inválido, ele pede que seja digitado outro. Se for válido, a função retorna o valor.

Um detalhe é que você não está usando o retorno para nada, talvez devesse fazer algo como `valor = pergunta()` e depois usa o `valor` no restante do programa.

---

A outra resposta sugeriu usar recursão, que até "funciona", mas [não é a melhor opção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052). Isso porque cada chamada recursiva vai ocupando espaço na pilha de execução, e se forem digitados muitos números inválidos, pode ocorrer um [estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001) ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/iTz8Sb) - vá até o final da página e veja o erro).

Já usando `while`, só uma chamada é feita e não ocorre o estouro de pilha, independente de quantos números inválidos forem digitados.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você tem que entender que `return` é uma palavra reservada do python, que serve para retornar um valor e encerrar a função. Assim que o `return` é executado, a função para. Portanto, a sua função `pergunta()` vai pedir um número inteiro e salvá-lo na variável `t`, se esse número for menor que `3`, a função vai printar `tente outro` na tela, vai retornar o valor de `t` e encerrar a execução. entretanto, esse valor retornado não está sendo armazenado em canto algum, então ele fica perdido. Se você quer que a função seja executada novamente, ao invés de encerrar, retire o `return`, substituindo-o por uma chamada recursiva. Assim:

```
def pergunta():
    t = int(input('digite um numero: '))
    dois = t<3
    if dois:
        print ('tente outro')
        pergunta()
    else:
        print ('esse numero ai, parabéns')

pergunta()
```

A diferença aqui é que quando o `if dois` é executado, a função printa `tente outro` na tela e chama a si mesma. Ou seja, a função é executada por ela mesma, é isso que se chama recursividade. Agora vamos entender melhor o funcionamento do `return`. Como já dito, ela encerra a função e retorna um valor, considere o exemplo:

```
def pergunta():
    t = int(input('digite um numero: '))
    dois = t<3
    if dois:
        print ('valor menor que 3')
        return t
    else:
        print ('valor maior ou igual a 3')
        return t

pergunta()
```

Um simples programa que coleta um valor, diz se ele é menor ou não que três e retorna o dito valor. A pergunta aqui é, se ele retorna um valor, onde fica armazenado? Bem, isso deve ser especificado no código. Imagine um programa que consiste numa única linha de código:

```
4
```

Esse programa não faz absolutamente nada. Se quisermos armazenar esse valor em algum lugar, o ideal seria:

```
algumLugar = 4
```

O mesmo vale pras funções, se quisermos armazenar o retorno da função `pergunta()` em algum lugar, devemos, ao invés de:

```
pergunta()
```

Usar:

```
retorno = pergunta()
```

Então, o valor de `t`, que é o que a função retorna, será armazenado na variável `retorno`, e para ver este valor, basta adicionar um `print(retorno)`