# Como diminuir o tempo da busca visual com pyautogui.locateOnScreen?

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um 'bot' de reconhecimento de imagens onde caso ele encontre a imagem X ele aperta NUM1 e se encontra a imagem Y ele aperta NUM3. Ele funcionar normalmente porém as vezes vejo que ele demora até 2s para executar essa ação, pelo que eu li na documentação do pyautogui é realmente esse tempo médio de leitura da tela.

**Tem algum outro comando de leitura de tela que seja mais rápido?**

```
import pyautogui,os,win32gui
from time import sleep

def loop():
    global anel,colar,k,n
    window = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
    #print(window)

    if "Tibia" in window:
        while True:
            #Procura IMG
            pyautogui.locateOnWindow
            localAnel = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(anel)
            localColar = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(colar)

            #Se localizar a img
            if localAnel != None:
                pyautogui.press("NUM1")
                loop()
                #break
            if localColar != None:
                pyautogui.press("NUM3")
                loop()
                #break

    else:
        sleep(0.2)
        loop()
#configs
caminho = './img/'
os.chdir(caminho)
global anel,colar,k,n
anel = 'sem_ring.png'
colar = 'sem_amuleto.png'

#Stop Conditions
k = 0
n = 5

loop()
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Imagens são processos complicados de analisar, ~2s já é um tempo incrivelmente rápido para localizar visual na tela, não consigo imaginar mais rápido que isso. Algo que talvez ajude seria usar imagens em preto-e-branco, pode fazer isso ao setar o `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(, grayscale=True)`, no entanto isso aumenta o numero de falsos positivos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tem alguma forma de limitar a área de procura? tipo eu sei que essa imagem vai aparecer entre os pixels(x1,y2)~(x2,y2) creio que se limitar deva ficar mais rapido

Comment: Editei o titulo da sua pergunta, porque titulos tem que ser claros e devem ser sobre o problema especifico (que no caso é sobre melhorar o tempo do locateOnScreen). Em futuras perguntas ao invés de fornecer o seu código próprio, crie um [mcve] do problema, algo simplificado, semelhante ao da calculadora que fiz na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/540872/3635). Todos códigos postados no site devem ser "exemplos minimos", sem dependências desnecessárias e devem se focar no problema especifico.

Comment: Eu acho que esse código não vai rodar bem. Depender da performance do pyautogui para "swapar" ring e amuleto pode ser um problema. Além da questão de ser um prato cheio para o Battle Eye. Acho que você tem mais a perder, do que a ganhar com isso. De todo modo, caso seja só um estudo, boa sorte!

Comment: @EduardoGarciadeOliveira seria algo mais pra estudo mesmo, e pra usar em OTs. Pra usar no Global achei um feito também em Python que utilizar o OBS para fazer as verificações.

Answer (score 4):

Seu script tem alguns problemas, por exemplo o uso desnecessário da função recursiva, você pode resolver tudo no `while`, ficando no mesmo escopo, assim evitando problemas que a recursão poderia causar. Para entender melhor, recomendo que leia:

> [Quando usar recursão e quando usar laços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/3635)

Voltando ao código, criei um [**Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para clicar no botão com o número <kbd>6</kbd> da calculadora do Windows 10 (que é um programa que todo usuário de Windows tem e poderá testar assim o código *sem dependências desnecessárias*). Então com um screenshot da tela, peguei a imagem do botão com número <kbd>6</kbd> e salvei em um `.png`, exemplo:

> [image: botão com número 6 da calculadora do Windows 10 (calc.exe)]

No código não foi necessário o uso de *função recursiva*, tudo pode ser resolvido com um único `while`.

### Acelerando a localização com [`pyautogui`](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/).

Para tornar mais rápido a checagem da imagem usei o [**`grayscale=True`**](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#grayscale-matching), pois imagens com cores mais simples, em preto e branco serão mais rápidas, mas notei que isso pode causar **falsos positivos** se **não** for bem trabalhado.

Para melhorar a precisão você pode usar o parâmetro **`confidence=`**, isso é útil caso a função não consiga localizar uma imagem devido a **diferenças insignificantes de pixel**. Para usar o `confidence` é necessário instalar o [**OpenCV para Python**](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) usando o comando:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Exemplo:

```py
import pyautogui
from os import path
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
from time import sleep

btn6_asset = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)) + r"\btn6.png"

while True:
    # Obtém o texto da janela ativa
    title = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())

    # Checa se a janela ativa é a da calculadora
    if "Calculadora" in title:
        btn_found = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
            btn6_asset,
            grayscale=True,
            confidence=0.9
        )

        if btn_found is not None:
            # Extrai o x e y do elemento encontrado
            x, y, *extras = btn_found

            pyautogui.click(x, y)
        else:
            print("Imagem não encontrada")
    else:
        print("Janela não está ativa ou o programa não esta aberto")

    sleep(0.2)
```

Exemplo do processo:

> [image: pyautogui clicando no botão 6 do programa calc.exe]

---

### Delimitando a área de buscado do `pyautogui.locateOnScreen`

O método `pyautogui.locateOnScreen(...)` tem a propriedade **`region=(left, top, width, height)`** que permitirá delimitar a uma área para pesquisar a imagem, o que pode tornar o script mais rápido, já que provavelmente irá pesquisar em uma área menor, principalmente se tiver muitos objetos ou imagens na tela.

Para definir os valores de `left`, `top`, `width` e `height` no `region=(...)` da janela desejada (no exemplo a janela ativa), você pode usar o [**`win32gui` (pywin32)**](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/), para instalar use o comando:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Isso irá prover acesso as APIs do Windows, então usando o método [**`win32gui.GetWindowRect(<janela>)`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) que irá retornar os valores necessários, algo como:

```py
import pyautogui
from os import path
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow, GetWindowRect, GetWindowText
from time import sleep

btn6_asset = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)) + r"\btn6.png"

while True:
    # Obtem a janela ativa
    window = GetForegroundWindow()

    # Checa se a janela ativa é a da calculadora
    if "Calculadora" in GetWindowText(window):

        # Obtém a região da janela ativa
        wx, wy, ww, wh = GetWindowRect(window)

        # Corrige x e y negativos de algumas "decorações" de janelas
        # ajusta a largura e altura da região buscada
        win_region = (
            max(wx, 0), # Se o valor for negativo define como 0
            max(wy, 0), # Se o valor for negativo define como 0
            ww - wx,    # Desconta o valor de x da largura
            wh - wy     # Desconta o valor de y da altura
        )

        btn_found = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
            btn6_asset,
            grayscale=True,
            confidence=0.9,
            region=win_region
        )

        if btn_found is not None:
            # Extrai o x e y do elemento encontrado
            x, y, *extras = btn_found

            pyautogui.click(x, y)
        else:
            print("Imagem não encontrada")
    else:
        print("Janela não está ativa ou o programa não esta aberto")

    sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Obrigado irei fazer os testes aqui, realmente sou um zero a esquerda em recursividade

Comment: @CarlosChagasJunior teste da forma que sugeri em me diga se no seu código melhorou o tempo

Comment: sim melhorou bastante, muito obrigado

Comment: @CarlosChagasJunior tinha um erro no primeiro exemplo que fiz com GetWindowRect. Atualizei a resposta, agora funcionará corretamente. Note que usar `region=` parece que ele tem um limite de tamanho da janela.